# Polarization between a Quarter Wave plate and half wave plate

Tags: polarization

Use a Quarter Wave Plate to obtain a circular polarized beam. What happens if you place a Half Wave Plate in the path of the circularly polarized light?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear related to programming.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.